# RecycleView , some items' subView doesn't show correctly

Tags: android-recyclerview

in fragment

```
mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
        mRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
        mRV.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration.Builder()
                .setOffsetLeft(ScreenUtil.dip2px(getActivity(), 60 + 10) + this.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.horizontal_margin))
                .build(getActivity());
        mRV.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
        mRV.setItemViewCacheSize(15);
        mRV.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

in adapter

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MessageItemHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.w_message_item,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ((RVItemInterface)holder).setAdapter(this);
    ((RVItemInterface)holder).update(dataList.get(position),position);
}
```

in holder

```
public class MessageItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements RVItemInterface{

private RoundAvatar mAvatar;
private TextView mTitle;
private TextView mContent;
private TextView mTime;

private BaseRVAdapter mAdapter;

private MsgDecorVo mMsgDecorVo;

...

@Override
public void update(Object obj, final int position) {
    reset();
    mMsgDecorVo = (MsgDecorVo) obj;

    if(mMsgDecorVo.type == MsgDecorVo.TYPE_CATEGORY){
        updateCategory();
        MsgVo msgVo = mMsgDecorVo.msgVo;
        if(msgVo.getMsg() == null || msgVo.getMsg().equals("")){
            mContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            mContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mContent.setText(msgVo.getMsg());
        }
        if(msgVo.getTime() == 0){
            mTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            mTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mTime.setText(TimeUtil.transformLong2DateString(msgVo.getTime()));
        }

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dealCategoryClick();
            }
        });

    }else if(mMsgDecorVo.type == MsgDecorVo.TYPE_CONVERSATION){

        ...

        mContent.setText(ImUtil.getMsgContent(message));
        mTime.setText(TimeUtil.transformLong2DateString(message.getMsgTime()));

        if(chatUserVo != null){
            ..

        }else {
            ..
        }
    }
}

//
private void updateCategory(){
    ...
}

//
private void dealCategoryClick(){
    ...
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
    mAdapter = (BaseRVAdapter) adapter;
}

@Override
public void reset() {
    mAvatar.setOnClickListener(null);
    mAvatar.setAvatar(R.drawable.avatar_default_circle);
    mAvatar.hideTagBottom();
    mAvatar.hideTagTop();
}
```

}

these code in holder

```
        mContent.setText(ImUtil.getMsgContent(message));
        mTime.setText(TimeUtil.transformLong2DateString(message.getMsgTime()));
```

has run

but when I scrolled,some of items doesn't show correctly ,the time and content was gone!
if I notify the recyclerview ,it goes right, and if i scroll again,it will still be wrong

just like the image,you can see some items' (time & content) was gone!

http://g.picphotos.baidu.com/album/s%3D900%3Bq%3D90/sign=297cc7510946f21fcd345253c61f1a5d/a686c9177f3e6709378bcc5538c79f3df9dc5595.jpg "tooltip"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't have the full code but I assume it is happening because you are not resetting your view states properly.

For Instance, in your updateCode, if type = TYPE_CATEGORY, you set the `mTime`'s visibility depending on whether `getTime` is 0 or not. But as you scroll, that row might be re-used for 
TYPE_CONVERSATION in which case, `mTime`'s visibility will NOT be updated.